# Mac OS X issue: new Finder window is "blank" until Force Quit > Relaunch

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

Machine is a '06 Mac Pro 1.1 running OS X Mavericks (installed via SFOTT) Sorry, don't have enough of a "reputation" yet to post links, so you'll have to Google 'SFOTT for Mac' if you're unfamiliar with it. Basically it's a workaround for getting a x64 OS like Mavericks installed. This Mac Pro doesn't natively support an OS newer than Lion (x86 CPU), but I've seen no issues directly correlated to the SFOTT install.

When I open a new Finder window, the center of the window where the files/folder should be is either just blank, transparent or has garbled graphics. This ONLY happens with Finder, no other programs have any display issues at all. Here's an example:

[image: Garbled graphics]

One more example:

[image: gray background in Finder window (this is sometimes transparent instead and shows the OS X background image thru Finder)]

I work as a SysAdmin for a living, but on Windows mostly. What could be the issue here? So far I have tried:

- Booting to Mavericks USB installer > Disk Utility > Check Disk (it passes) & running Repair Permissions on OS X partition.

Could the graphics card be failing? Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: I think it's impossible to tell which is at fault, without either resorting to Apple Service Diagnostics to test hardware, or restoring an authorized version of OSX onto the machine and seeing if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't roll back to Lion, the machine would be worthless to me. I need to find a fix for this OS or I'll have to just replace the machine.

Comment: You can always make a bootable USB of Lion and test it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This machine was re-purposed as a VMware ESXi 6 host, but presumably this was a hardware issue with the graphics card. I removed the graphics card before installing the new OS (VMware ESXi) and have had no issues since then.